# How to extract .tar.gz file in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-15.10

I want to extract an archive named `kdiff3.tar.gz`.

Using `tar -xzvf kdiff3.tar.gz`, doesn't extract the file. It gives this error:

```
   gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
   tar: Child returned status 1
   tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Using `file kdiff3.tar.gz` gives this message:

```
   kdiff3.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text
```

It would be great, if someone could help.

Comment: Since the file is an HTML document you cannot extract it.

Comment: The package kdiff3-0.9.98.tar.gz : http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/kdiff3/kdiff3-0.9.98.tar.gz/b52f99f2cf2ea75ed5719315cbf77446/kdiff3-0.9.98.tar.gz ... Or http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/files/kdiff3/  ..... No issues with `tar xvf kdiff3-0.9.98.tar.gz`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score -2):

The file may be not gzip file. you can try the following steps.

```
mv "filename".tar.gz "filename".tar
tar xvf "filename".tar
```